# Android Studio - How to read (Line) from a text file?

Tags: java, android, text, stream, filereader

Right now my code looks like that:

```
private ImageButton nextButton;
private TextView textView;
private int stringIndex = 0;
private String[] dialog = {
            "You: Hey, how are you?",
            "She: I am fine and you?",
            "You: I am fine as well!",
            "She: Nice to meet you!"};

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_restaurant);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        nextButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){


                if (stringIndex == dialog.length-1){
                    stringIndex = 0;
                    textView.setText(dialog[stringIndex]); 
                } else {
                    textView.setText(dialog[++stringIndex]); 
                }
      }
```

It works fine but what is bothering me is the String array. I prefer to save that dialog in a text file and read it line by line whenever I click on that button.
I saw some solution with assets and FileReader/BuffedReader but I am stucked and need your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good tutorial about FileInputStream, FileOutputStream and BufferedReader. It's easy to understand the examples.

https://www.androidauthority.com/lets-build-a-simple-text-editor-for-android-773774/

Comment: I know how to read a file and read a line from a text file in a normal Java application but I have problems here in Android Studio somehow. How can I implement the FileReader that it reads the line onClick?